# Display cells on screen that have error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an error handler setup that allows the user to update incorrect data when the Macro detects an error.  The problem is the macro is checking a large volume of data and the user can't see the cell in question I'm asking them to update.  What can I add to this error handler to allow the user see the cell on screen before they input the correct result into the inpput box?  Thanks.

```
ErrPrice:
rngEachValue.value = InputBox ("Input correct Price here")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can highlight the cell with:

```
rngEachValue.Activate
```

This way, the cell will be selected and surrounded. Alternatively, if you use `rngEachValue.Copy`afterwards, you'll even see the "moving" selection...

Comment: Is there any way to show the cell without using "activate" as the macro is using a large volume of data.

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue then. Even if the macro runs on a large set of data, I understood you're prompting the user to enter _a_ value in case a errors - this only one cell needs to be activated at a time, right?

Comment: agreed - I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: However if I have multiple cells to update - .activate will slow the performance of the macro.

Comment: just place the `.activate` in your error handler! this way it will only get called when the problem occurs and not slow the execution down!